# Procedural parameters in xcode

Tags: c, xcode, parameters

is it possible to get procedural paramters working in xcode? I am working on an assignment for university, and would like to use the debugger in xcode to help me learn whats going on.

I know the code is at the very minimum compilable, because i was able to compile it with gcc, but xcode does not recognize the syntax.

the code i'm trying to run in xcode is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
    int a = 50; 
    int b = 100;

    void P(int *c, void R(int)) {
        void Q(int p) {
            printf("%d\n", p);
            R(p+100);
        }
        if (a == b) R(b);
        else {c = c + 25;
            P(c, Q); 
        }
    }

    void Q(int p) {
        printf("%d\n", p);
    }

    P(&a,Q);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode uses the `clang` compiler by default, which [does not support nested functions](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#gcc-extensions-not-implemented-yet). To use `gcc` in Xcode, go to your project settings, select your target and change **Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C** to `LLVM GCC 4.2`. Now if you compile, `gcc` will complain, that nested functions are not enabled. Go back to your target settings, **LLVM GCC 4.2 Language** and under **Other C Flags** add `-fnested-functions`. Your project should compile now.